# Free Will after Exodus

Tags: history, hashkafah-philosophy, nevua-prophecy, free-will-bechira

There are many sources<sup>e.g. 1,2</sup>, that discuss what happened to the world after the splitting of the sea, and the giving of the Torah, implying that the whole world heard what happened. Everyone knew about Hashem and the Torah. E.g. how Amalek [came and cooled](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Deuteronomy.25.18.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) those "hot waters" of faith in Hashem.

Do any sources discuss how this affected free will? Do any sources explain exactly why this sort of free-will reducing event was able to happen, and why then and only then? (and [seemingly when Moshiach comes as well](https://www.sefaria.org/Micah.7.15?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=bi), but [that's a different question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9694/will-there-be-free-will-and-a-purpose-to-doing-good-in-the-messianic-era))

---

<sup>1 - [Is there a midrash that says all of the water in the world split at the time of the splitting of the reed sea?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/114551/is-there-a-midrash-that-says-all-of-the-water-in-the-world-split-at-the-time-of)

2 - [The Torah offered to other nations](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98742/the-torah-offered-to-other-nations)</sup>

Comment: This is not "free-will reducing". People still had to struggle with their natures, and indeed began sinning sometimes, right away afterwards. It's just that they were struggling with a different set of choices. No one sane walks in front of a moving truck that they can see, and they had a very clear perception of some things that are murky to us.

Comment: I know people like to say, "If G-d would only appear to me and tell me what to do, then I would ___!" Usually they are wrong; they underestimate their yetzer hara's resilience.